# how to add a block to the existing template in magento

Tags: magento

I have following template defined in layout.xml

```
<action method="setTemplate" ifconfig="ot_settings/header/type" condition="1"><template>page/html/header_type2.phtml</template></action>
```

I would like to create a block that will consist of entire header_type2.phtml template.

Do I just create block tag around it? :

```
<block type="core/template" name="test">
  <action method="setTemplate" ifconfig="ot_settings/header/type" condition="1"><template>page/html/header_type2.phtml</template></action>
</block>
```

If so what should I use for block type = ".... " ?

Thanks

Comment: You can use "core/template" but if your phtml file have some code of your specific block than "modulename/blockname"

Comment: Thanks can you provide an example? Do not understand what do you mean by saying specific block?

Comment: for example you have used the ifconfig="ot_settings/header/type" so it may be there a module related to ot. and specific means the block of ot module.

Comment: sorry still do not understand

Comment: how to find block_type then?

Comment: what is exactly want to do..let me know I will help you.